# can I easily migrate a working root system from non-LVM partitions to LVM partitions?

Tags: 12.04, lvm

I am running an ubuntu 12.04 system with a lot of modifications on a system with two (identical) harddisks. At the moment those are not running any LVM partitions. I would like to start using LVM, but don't want to run the risk of a lot of down time if anything goes wrong.

Most of the how-tos I see talk about setting up a new system. I was wondering if it would be easily possible to set up LVM on the second disk (I can easily clear the entire disk for this purpose) and then migrate the system to that disk, freeing the first disk up to also be set up for LVM.

Is that at all possible?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/493481/fastest-way-to-convert-an-ext4-formatted-disk-to-lvm-with-ext4-on-it